# HTML email gap in outlook 2013

Tags: html, email, outlook

I wrote a simple html email template that seems to render fine in all email clients EXCEPT outlook 2013.   I've simplified the code to illustrate the problem below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>K</title>
<style type="text/css">
   table {border-collapse: collapse;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; background-color:#70b9b9; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background:black;padding:0;"><img src="http://jl.evermight.net/outlook2013/pic.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="display:block; border:none;" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with this code is that there's a black gap between the green and the image, which I can show here:

[image]

So how i get rid of this black gap?  Again, this is only a problem in outlook2013

Comment: Try adding `display: block;` to that image. This usually fixes extra padding in image elements.

Comment: Try setting the height on both the image and the cell as height="...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to zero out the padding and margin in the image. You should probably set at least the width of the image too, even if it is `width="100%"`.

Here is my basic image setup:

```
<td>
  <img alt="" src="" width="" height="" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
</td>
```

Also, Outlook has issues with cells shorter than 19px, so make sure your image is tall enough.

Other unrelated notes:

- Get rid of `<tbody>` it does nothing in html email
- change `background:black;` to `background-color:#000000;`, html email needs the 6-digit hex color